# React test throwing warning 'Invalid DOM property `%s`. Did you mean `%s`?%s'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component as such:

```
const a = {
 b: 'test',
 c: fn(),
 d: {
   e: 'test'
 }
};

<A propA={a} />
A.propTypes = {
 propA: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

I am testing this component using JEST and Enzyme so my test looks something like this:

```
const a = {
 b: 'test',
 c: jest.fn(),
 d: {
   e: 'test'
 }
};

Enzyme.configure({
 adapter: new Adapter(),
});

const mounter = mount(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <A propA={a} />
  </BrowserRouter>,
);
...
...
```

I use `<BrowserRouter>` to test it, since I am using react-router for my application routes. I have tests to ensure the component is rendered correctly.

However, this test breaks with the below warning:

> Warning: Invalid DOM property `%s`. Did you mean `%s`?%s

Could anyone please help me debug why this error is being thrown?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this code and not the `<A />` component?

Comment: I think so, because the propType for property {a} is an object and is defined in the component as such - please refer to my edited post, I added the propType definition as it is in my code. Since it is an object, I would think that the warning could not have corresponded to that component... But I am open to all suggestions!

Comment: Normally pasting doesn't alter code.

Comment: What does the A component render?

Comment: In any case, my suggestion remains the same--I don't think the error is here.

Comment: Hello @zord, it renders couple of divs, and 2 React components that ultimately render a button, hyperlink and some text.

Comment: I think the error might be there. For example you passed in "class" instead of "className" to one of those. Or something similar.

Comment: I found the issue, I do not understand it though. As mentioned, it was coming from the components that A renders. One of the CSS attributes on the div was "tabindex='0'". If I change it to "tabIndex='0'" - capitalize the "i" in 'tabindex', it works.        Not sure why that is though.

Comment: Found why - http://www.chrislane.info/using-tabindex-in-react/

Comment: Because that's how HTML element properties work in React. Same with CSS property names etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why this was happening. The above error was not coming from my test, it was coming out of one of the divs that component A was rendering.

One of them had 'tabindex' property set to make them focussable. And in React, these properties need to be camel-cased. Hence 'tabindex' becomes 'tabIndex' and 'classname' becomes 'className' and so on. Once I fixed that, the above warning disappears.

Source - http://www.chrislane.info/using-tabindex-in-react/